# jquery to get href in anchor tag using div/span ID selector and anchor tag class

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I'm new to jquery I just wanted to seek some help on getting the href attr in anchor tag using div/span ID selector and anchor tag class

```
<span id="view-post-btn"><a href="https://blog.company.com/site1/archives/team/post-1" class="button button-small">View Member</a></span>


<div id="preview-action">
<a class="preview button"  href="https://blog.company.com/site1/archives/team/post-1"  target="wp-preview" id="post-preview">Preview Changes</a>
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this.

```
$('#view-post-btn').find('a.button').attr('href');
$('#preview-action').find('a.preview').attr('href');
```

Answer (score 6):

try

```
$('#view-post-btn').find('a').attr('href');
$('#preview-action').find('a').attr('href');
```

Comment: Thanks Maikay, This is working but how can we filter it further with a class in <a> tag as there will be other pages that will use this .

Comment: instead of `find('a')` you are able to use jQuery selectors in the find method e.g. `find('a.button')` so you want to find the class **button** in an <a>-tag (look @SPEC answere)